Add bank account to stripe connect custom accounts
I'm using Stripe Connect with Node.js and TypeScript on a platform that handles payments for third-party services we call "partners". We opted to use Stripe Connect's custom accounts to have full control over the user experience and all the related aspects concerning our partners in order to create a Stripe Connect ID for them. We already have the necessary information to create the custom account, but there's something we don't understand: How do we connect the bank account to this custom Stripe Connect account?
What data is needed for the bank account to be valid? And how can I verify if this data is correct before it's sent to the server?
I only have the following
const { id } = await stripe.accounts.create({
                ...
                type: 'custom',
                country,
                email,
                business_type: 'individual',
                ...
            });

I need help with this Stripe flow.

Did you have a look at the documentation?

Have a look at the various tabs and drilldowns on https://docs.stripe.com/connect/payouts-bank-accounts
You can build frontend forms, either using Stripe's Financial Connection product that links bank accounts, or your own basic HTML forms for collecting the bank account numbers, creating tokens with https://docs.stripe.com/js/tokens/create_token?type=bank_account and passing to https://docs.stripe.com/api/accounts/create#create_account-external_account
